Elastic Beanstalk error 128 "No url found for submodule path 'aws-elastic-beanstalk-cli-setup' in .gitmodules" in Windows
I have inherited a Ruby on Rails app hosted on AWS and managed by Elastic Beanstalk. I have completed the setup, with my AWS credentials, including separate ssh keys for both the staging environment. It seemed to work. I can run eb ssh vatic-admin-dev and access the staging environment, including the Rails console and whatnot. However, when I try to deploy with eb deploy vatic-admin-dev, I see the following error messages:
Alert: Your environment is using a deprecated platform branch. It might not be supported in the future.

Alert: The platform version that your environment is using isn't recommended. There's a recommended version in the same platform branch.

Creating application version archive "app-04be-240711_152417250263".
ERROR: CommandError - An error occurred while handling git command.
Error code: 128 Error: fatal: No url found for submodule path 'aws-elastic-beanstalk-cli-setup' in .gitmodules

The strangest thing is that it did deploy fine once or twice, but then I pushed a change to the branch and all of a sudden it doesn't work. The coworker who set this all up back in the day doesn't seem to know much about it beyond the basics and has never seen this error before. I'm hoping it's something simple I just don't know about.
